# How to Install specific version of a plugin with Grafana-cli?

Tags: grafana, grafana-plugin

I came across an issue where I need  to install a specific version of a plugin in Grafana, I tried command `grafana-cli plugins install jdbranham-diagram-panel --version=1.6.1` which didn't work. I am trying to install `jdbranham-diagram-panel`  plugin's `1.6.1` version in my system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following command should do the trick.

```
grafana-cli plugins install jdbranham-diagram-panel 1.6.1
```

In above command I needed to install plugin named `jdbranham-diagram-panel` with version `1.6.1` so we can use above command to do so.

Basically syntax of installing any plugin with specific version will become like:

```
grafana-cli plugins install plugin_name  plugin_version
```